# City tickets as exchange objects?

Tags: geocaching

Is it good idea to use city **tickets** for public transport (laminated or in string bags) as exchange objects or traveller objects (**krets**)? Are such items welcomed by the geocachers community?

From the one side, simply throwing validated tickets into caches in the same city is not welcomed, because such 'items' are considered thrash. But from the other side, the ticket from the other city (or the other country) can be welcomed by collectors, and when it is secured from wet (lamination etc.) it can look quite nice in the cache.

[image]

Comment: This is subjective and open ended, hard to come up with concrete answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal opinion: **Yes.**

Once, while hiking in the mountains, I found by chance a ~30 year old train ticket for transporting some freight between two train stations that have now been closed a long time ago. I love railway history as I love hiking, and it's a nice collectors item. If the ticket is from an exotic place or a place far away in space or in time, I think it's really nice.

That being said, this is my personal opinion, and other people may have different opinions.